# AWS RDS:user/redshift is not authorized to perform: rds:DescribeDBInstances

Tags: amazon-web-services

I tried to check if instances still exist with AWS CLI

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --query 'DBInstances[*].[DBName,DBInstanceIdentifier]' --output text
```

I have configured `aws configure` when I was learning about redshift

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DescribeDBInstances operation: User: arn:aws:iam::577147542553:user/redshift is not authorized to perform: rds:DescribeDBInstances
```

My IAM users

[image]

How to find out which user can list AWS RDS from terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are 2 ways to find out IAM Permissions of a user -**

**1. Individual user -**
If you know the username whose permission you want to find out,
Simply got to IAM and click on the username
You will be able to find the individually associated IAM permission of the user.
As well as the Policies inherited by the user from the Groups which hs/she is a part of.

**2. Groups -**
If you don't know the username, but probably know the group the user is a part of,
Go to IAM and Click on the Group's name,
Similar to the Individual user's permission tab,
You will be able to find the IAM policies associated to the Group,
As well as the Inline policies attached to the Group.

Comment: Ok,user admin has RDSFullAccess permissions.